# How do i add comment fields in my page in WordPress

Tags: comments

How do i add comment fields in my page in WordPress

My page design is shown below, Please help me to add comment field under the video during playing.

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled comments option in wordpress admin ?

Comment: Do you mean WordPress comments for the currently viewed page/post, or Youtube comments from the video?

Comment: Thanks melvin and Chris Morris. I did successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check WordPress **Admin** and find **Settings** Menu. On clicking it you will find **Discussion** submenu.
Check the Image below for reference :)

[image]

By adding custom css you can make it more beautiful

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked under Admin -> Settings -> Discussion and for individual pages, under pages and quick-edit or the discussion area in edit page below the page editor?

When the last one does not show, click screen options near the top right, and tick discussion there, then scroll back down.

Comment: Thank you so much.